# MNIST Data set anomaly detection

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, encoder-decoder

I am trying to use MNIST data set for anomaly detection using Encoder with tensor flow, the  input of Encoder is normal and abnormal data , the question is how i divide MNIST to normal and abnormal data (exp the zeros are abnormal and the (1-9) are normal?

Comment: The split highly depends on what you are trying to achieve. For anomaly detection you could also check out [mnist_corrupted](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/catalog/mnist_corrupted) dataset which contains some images with perturbations in the test set.

Comment: i'm about to do a feed for an Encoder by data mnist splited in (0) as normal data , the others are anomalies